# aligning content in well format like products or items

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Am having a problem with my script, it can't align the info very well,

because if the center data has long characters than the next `<li>` then the whole align break.

so its not constant. that if the next `<li>` have long characters it will break it down to next line. to keep the align good like product or item align

so its a flex problem
that content should be inline even if other got long characters or small, they must be inline matching width

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <span class=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i> John</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <p class="">From</p>
      <p><small class="">Canada</small></p>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <p>Age</p>
      <p>23</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <span class=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i> John</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <p class="">From</p>
      <p><small class="">United Kingdom</small></p>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-auto">
      <p>Age</p>
      <p>23</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with your English, but if you want the columns to align you need a different layout. Flex rows don't relate to each other. Consider using a table, which seems more appropriate here.

Comment: ok thanks for idea